# How to prevent touch screen scrolling for input elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, mobile-safari

I have a modal on top of a scrollable document body and I want to prevent scrolling of the document body when I pan my finger on the modal.

```
$(document).on('touchstart touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

This piece of code works for everything except an input element.

```
<div id="modal">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

If I pan my finger within the input element, the document will continue to scroll. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, it is bubbling.
Add `e.stopPropagation()` to the body of your function.

```
$(document).on('touchstart touchmove', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```